# StringCommandHandler in Python-Telegram-Bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

How to make a bot can handle both "command" and "message" simultaneously?
I mean when the user types both command and message simultaneously, for example, "/add Hello World". How to make the bot understand that the user wants to run the "add" command and the message is "Hello World".

I have thought that "split" string could be possible. However, this way is somehow rigid.
So, I learned about "StringCommandHandler" in PTB, however, the documentation is quite confusing to get it.

Could anyone provide me an example of StringCommandHandler, or other possible solutions for this case? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the docs of [`StringCommandHandler`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.stringcommandhandler.html), that handler is not intended to handle updates from Telegram, so it is not related to your quesiton.

When using [`CommandHandler`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.commandhandler.html), the arguments coming after the `/command` are available via [`context.args`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.callbackcontext.html#telegram.ext.CallbackContext.args). In your case, when the user sends `/add Hello World`, you would have

```
context.args == ["Hello", "World"]
```

within the handler callback.

Custom parsing of `update.(effective_)message.text` is however still a perfectly valid option.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.